# Google sheets script - Strip extra data from a second line and add it to the first line

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a script in google sheets script that will iterate down a sheet, row by row, and if it encounters an ID number in the first cell of that row that is identical to the one above it, it strips out the data from every cell EXCEPT Column A and B, and appends it to the line above. Ideally, this would work with an indeterminate number of duplicate row IDs, might be 2, might be 3, might be 4.

After stripping out the data I want to keep (eg colums C and onward), I then want to delete the entire contents of the processed duplicate ID row, but I just haven't put that in my script until after it copies the data correctly.

In this example, sheet rows 6, 7 and 8 have identical ID numbers (Column A)

[image]

Here is the result I'm trying to get:

[image]

And here is the result I'm getting:

[image]

I've tried a number of different ways, and torn down and rebuilt my script a couple of times without getting the result I want:

```
function stripMiner() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1WDPoTICQvdruxfhAwHLtA51fz05DqyZ-NhNfpAyPO6Y");
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var startRow = 5;
  var numRows = mainSheet.getLastRow();//obtains the last row in the sheet
  var setrgh = mainSheet
  var dataRange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow, 1,4,120); //rowStart, columnStart, row count, column count, the columncount needs to be large enough to encompass all your ancillary data
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var iter = 0;
  var maxItRow = 4;
  var prevIdNum = 0;
  var dupCount = 1;
  var cc1 = "P5"; //Cells to dump check values into
  var cc2 = "P6";
  var dumpRow = startRow;
  //if (numRows >= maxItRow){var maxIter = maxItRow;}

  for (i in data){
    if (iter != maxItRow){ //making sure we haven't gone over the iteration limit
      var row = data[i];
      var idNum = (row[0]);
      var jCount = 0; //resets icount if the id number is different icount is used to skip some cells in a row

      if (idNum == prevIdNum){//only proceed if we've hit another line with the same ID number
        dupCount = +1; //increment the dupcount value
        mainSheet.getRange(cc2).setValue("dupCount"+dupCount); //dupcount check value
        var rowIterStart = 5; //RowIterStart is used to add to rowiter, EG if your data is 20 columns wide, and you start transposing from column 4, then this will want to be about 17
        var rowIter = 1;
        for (j in row){
          if (jCount >= 2){ //the integer here is the column where it will begin to transpose data
            mainSheet.getRange(dumpRow-1,(rowIterStart*dupCount)+(rowIter)).setValue(row[j]); //startRow+(iter-dupCount)

            mainSheet.getRange(cc1).setValue("dumprow"+dumpRow);
          }
          rowIter+=1;
          jCount +=1;
        }
      }
      else{
        var dupCount = 1;

        dumpRow +=1;
      }
      prevIdNum = (row[0]); //sets the most recently processed rows ID number 
    }
    iter +=1;
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

(Also I'm still just a beginner with this so if I've overlooked anything obvious or taken the wrong approach to do this, I apologize!)

Comment: OK can you post a link to your sheet and I will look to it tomorrow AM.

Comment: Does row 7 and 8 need to be blank or deleted altogether?

Comment: You're only checking for previous id. This is better done with a forward iteration than a backward one. Loop over data> for each data row, loop again over all remaining data to check for same ID.

Answer (score 0):

The results for the questioner's code in the case of copied data arise from a convoluted loop. In essence, though duplicates were identified, there was a mis-counting to assign the copied data to the correct rowID. So far as clearing data, no provision was included.

The following code works to meet the questioner's goals, though it is far from perfect.

At present, the recalculation of the "last column" after copy each duplicate is an absolute rather than than a row-based figure. So, if a duplicate was detected for, say, ID=3, the data would be copied to column 12 rather than column 6. This requires the addition of a simple dupID row counter.

The second factor is the calculation of the last column in the spreadsheet.
`var dataRange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow, 1,Rowlast+1,120);`
The questioner used 120 columns; and I have retained that number simply for the sake of consistency. The questioner should re-assess whether this is excessive.

---

```
function ejb_so_5284922701() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<  insert questioners spreadsheet ID>>");
    var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("<< insert questioner's sheet name >>");

    var startRow = 5;

    // calculate the last row containing data
    var Rowvals = ss.getRange("A5:A").getValues();
    var Rowlast = Rowvals.filter(String).length; //6
    Logger.log("last row = " + Rowlast); // DEBUG


    // calculate the last column containing data
    var cell = mainSheet.getRange("A5"); //or however you determine "cell"
    var drCol = mainSheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
    Logger.log('getLastColumn = ' + drCol); //DEBUG
    for (var i = drCol; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (mainSheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), i).getValue() != "") {
            break;
        }
    }
    var lastColumn = i;
    Logger.log("Last column  with data = " + lastColumn); //DEBUG



    var setrgh = mainSheet

    // numColumns neds to be reviewed 
    var dataRange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, Rowlast + 1, 120); //rowStart, columnStart, row count, column count, the column count needs to be large enough to encompass all your ancillary data
    // start row = 5, 1= column A, 4, rows, 120, columns
    Logger.log("startRow = " + startRow + ", and the datarange = " + dataRange.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG

    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    Logger.log("length of data =" + data.length); //DEBUG


    var lastid = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            // if this is the first row, then assign anything but zero to last id
            lastid = 100;
            Logger.log(" this is the first row; set last id to 100");
        }

        var thisid = data[i][0];

        // evaluate whether this is a duplicate ID
        if (thisid == lastid) {

            // this is a dup
            Logger.log("i=" + i + ". This is a dup" + ", name is " + data[i][2]); //DEBUG
            var stufftocopyrange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3, 1, 3);
            var stufftocopy = stufftocopyrange.getValues();
            Logger.log("the range to copy is " + stufftocopyrange.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG
            var targetrange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow + lastid - 1, lastColumn + 1, 1, 3);
            targetrange.setValues(stufftocopy);
            lastColumn = lastColumn + 3;
            var duprange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow + i, 1, 1, 5);
            Logger.log("the range to clear is " + duprange.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG
            duprange.clearContent();

        } else {
            // no dup

            //assign lastid value
            var lastid = thisid;
            Logger.log("i=" + i + ". No dup. Last id set to " + lastid); // DEBUG

        } // if

    } // end for loop

}
```

---

**BEFORE**
[image]

---

**AFTER**

### [image]

Answer (score 0):

The solutions previously posted didn't quite get the result I needed, however I managed to cobble together something that works for my purposes. It expects to see data in the format like:

[image]

And turn it into something like this:

[image]

Where it uses duplicate ID numbers (with an indeterminite number of duplicates) to pull only certain columns of data from the duplicate lines and append it to the first line.

```
function stripMiner() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1WDPoTICQvdruxfhAwHLtA51fz05DqyZ-NhNfpAyPO6Y");
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var startRow = 5;
  var numRows = mainSheet.getLastRow();//obtains the last row in the sheet
  var setrgh = mainSheet
  var dataRange = mainSheet.getRange(startRow, 1,3,120); //rowStart, columnStart, row count, column count, the columncount needs to be large enough to encompass all your ancillary data
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var iter = 0;
  var maxItRow = 4;
  var prevIdNum = 0;
  var dupCount = 1;
  var cc1 = "P5"; //Cells to dump check values into
  var cc2 = "P6";
  var dumpRow = startRow;
  //if (numRows >= maxItRow){var maxIter = maxItRow;}

  for (i in data){
    if (iter != maxItRow){ //making sure we haven't gone over the iteration limit
      var row = data[i];
      var idNum = (row[0]);
      var jCount = 0; //resets icount if the id number is different icount is used to skip some cells in a row

      if (idNum == prevIdNum){//only proceed if we've hit another line with the same ID number
        dupCount = +1; //increment the dupcount value
        mainSheet.getRange(cc2).setValue("dupCount"+dupCount); //dupcount check value
        var rowIterStart = 5; //RowIterStart is used to add to rowiter, EG if your data is 20 columns wide, and you start transposing from column 4, then this will want to be about 17
        var rowIter = 1;
        for (j in row){
          if (jCount >= 2){ //the integer here is the column where it will begin to transpose data
            mainSheet.getRange(dumpRow-2,(rowIterStart*dupCount)+(rowIter)).setValue(row[j]); //startRow+(iter-dupCount)

            mainSheet.getRange(cc1).setValue("dumprow"+dumpRow);
          }
          rowIter+=1;
          jCount +=1;
        }
      }
      else{
        var dupCount = 1;

        dumpRow +=1;
      }
      prevIdNum = (row[0]); //sets the most recently processed rows ID number 
    }
    iter +=1;
  }
}
```

Hopefully someone else who wants to do a similar thing can make use of this too.